# how to return value from tornado.ioloop.IOLoop instance add_future method

Tags: python, tornado, rethinkdb, coroutine

I'm using `RethinkDB` with `Tornado` with an async approach. Base on my data model in `RethinkDB`, upon inserting a record for my `topic` table, I also have to update/insert new record into `user_to_topic` table. Here's the basic set up of my post request handler.

```
class TopicHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     pass

  @gen.coroutine
  def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # to establish databse connection
      connection = rth.connect(host='localhost', port=00000, db=DATABASE_NAME)
      # Thread the connection
      threaded_conn = yield connection

      title = self.get_body_argument('topic_title')
      # insert into table
      new_topic_record = rth.table('Topic').insert({
         'title': topic_title,
     }, conflict="error",
         durability="hard").run(threaded_conn)

     # {TODO} for now assume the result is always written successfully
     io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
     # I want to return my generated_keys here 
     io_loop.add_future(new_topic_record, self.return_written_record_id)
     # do stuff with the generated_keys here, how do I get those keys

  def return_written_record_id(self, f):
     _result = f.result()
     return _result['generated_keys']
```

after the insert operation finishes, the `Future` object with return result from `RethinkDB` insert operation through `Future.result()` method which I can retrieve id of new record using `generated_keys` attribute of result. According to `Tornado` [document](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_future), I can do stuff with the result in my callback function, `return_written_record_id`. Of course I can do all the other database operations inside my `return_written_record_id` function, but is it possible to return all the ids to my `post` function? Or this is the way it has to be using coroutine in tornado?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
result = yield new_topic_record
```

Whenever you yield a Future inside a coroutine, Tornado pauses the coroutine until the Future is resolved to a value or exception. Then Tornado resumes the coroutine by passing the value in or raising an exception at the "yield" expression.

For more info, see [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).